# Ignore Asp.Net Core MVC route with webpack HMR

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, webpack-dev-server

I have webpack & asp.net mvc core working fine.

I only have one bundle configured.

There is only one problem with HMR.

The web pack dev server is running at this address:

`http://127.0.0.1:64579/dist/__webpack_hmr`

With my brother if I go to this address and use the default route:
`http://127.0.0.1:64579/`

Everything works fine.

If I go to a specific route: `http://127.0.0.1:64579/home/index`

Chrome tries to open the dev server at this address: `http://127.0.0.1:64579/home/dist/__webpack_hmr`

Is there a way to configure the dev server in webpack.config.js to ignore the mvc route parameters and use only the base address?

Answer (score 1):

I found it... I hate me :)

```
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
```

And the fixed version, I was the leading slash in the publicPath property.

```
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
```